Unable to Create Files Adjacent to User-Selected File Due to App Sandbox Permissions
I am developing a macOS app that requires the ability to create new files in the same directory as a user-selected file, but I am encountering permission issues due to the App Sandbox restrictions. While the user can select a file (e.g., a.jpg) using a standard open panel, I cannot create an adjacent file (e.g., a.jxl) in the same folder because the sandbox only grants access to the selected file, not to other files in the directory.
I understand that full disk access might be an option, but it requires user intervention and isn't suitable for this case. Is there any way to extend access to other files in the directory (including those not selected by the user) while remaining within the App Sandbox environment?

I don't really understand, what are you trying to accomplish. But you can only open files in the users documents directory, if the user selects this file. You can't open any users files without letting him know, which is a good thing Otherwise unlimited security problems would be at hand.

@LukeSideWalker if a user selects a file a.jpg, I want to create a file a.txt next to it. I don't want to read anything than the user selected input, I want to create a side file

Nonetheless I don't really understand what a "side file" can even be, but as far as I understand, you want to let the user make a file choice (open file), then you want to create a text file, which of course you can not store in the users documents area, without the users help (you could though in the apps sandbox). So you have to offer "save at" dialogue with your text file and then EVENTUALLY the user will save at the file at the suggested folder or another one he likes.

The App Sandbox restricts access to only the file explicitly selected by the user, which can make it challenging to create adjacent files in the same directory. However, you can work around this limitation by using security-scoped bookmarks to extend access to the directory containing the selected file.

@Ujiwal_Pathak I couldn't get a security-scoped bookmark on the parent directory after the user selected a file. Do you do something special? I might be missing something

@Fractale No, you're not missing anything. The answer by Ujiwal looks like copied from ChatGPT or the like. Very prosaic and not correct. There's no way to programmatically extend the scope from a file to the enclosing directory without asking the user for permission.

If your App just creates files with the same name as the selected one but with different extension, you may use the so called related file access NSIsRelatedItemType to  extends your app’s sandbox to give your app access to the supporting file.
Otherwise let the user select the directory where to store the new files and persist the security scope as described in documentation: Persist access to files with security-scoped URL bookmarks
